# Need to keep star rating values after submission if errors occur only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a rating script that works fine but when I submit the rating and there is an error of some kind during the submitting process the star ratings go back to displaying no stars at all. For example, lets say I give a rating of two stars and then submit the rating and some kind of error occurs during the submitting process the stars for some reason go back to zero. I want to be able to keep the stars and value even when an error occurs so when the form displays the errors the users rating is still viewable and they wont have to re-enter their rating again. And then if the submission process is successful the star rating and value can go back to their default values.

Here is my JsFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/znoxgg6k/

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rating = 'eunrated';
    $('.rating-choice li')
        .on('mouseenter touchstart', function(){
            $(this).parent().removeClass($(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
            var classSuffix = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
            $('.rating-choice').addClass('erating-' + classSuffix);
            $('.rate-this').text($(this).data('desc'));
        })
        .on('mouseleave touchend', function(){
            var classSuffix = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
            $('.rate-this').text($('.rate-this').attr('data-desc'));
            $('.rating-choice').attr('class', '').addClass('rating-choice ' + rating)
        })
        .on('change click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('.rate-this').attr('data-desc', $(this).attr('data-desc'));
            rating = 'erating-' + $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
            $('.rating-choice').removeClass('eunrated').addClass(rating);
            $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
        });

        $('#clear-rating').on('change click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).parent().find('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
            $(this).parent().find('ul').removeClass().addClass('rating-choice eunrated');
            $('.rate-this').text($('.rate-this').attr('data-desc'));
            $('.rate-this').attr('data-desc', 'Rating').text('Rating');
            rating = 'eunrated';
        });
});
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form">
    <fieldset>
        <ol>
            <li><h2 class="header">Rating:</h2></li>
            <li>
                <ul class="rating-choice eunrated">
                    <li id="rate-1" data-desc="A">
                        <label for="rating-1"><input type="radio" value="1" name="rating" id="rating-1"  />0.5 stars</label>
                    </li>
                    <li id="rate-2" data-desc="B">
                        <label for="rating-2"><input type="radio" value="2" name="rating" id="rating-2"  />1 star</label>
                    </li>
                    <li id="rate-3" data-desc="C">
                        <label for="rating-3"><input type="radio" value="3" name="rating" id="rating-3"  />1.5 stars</label>
                    </li>
                    <li id="rate-4" data-desc="D">
                        <label for="rating-4"><input type="radio" value="4" name="rating" id="rating-4"  />2 stars</label>
                    </li>
                    <li id="rate-5" data-desc="E">
                        <label for="rating-5"><input type="radio" value="5" name="rating" id="rating-5"  />2.5 stars</label>
                    </li>
                    <li id="rate-6" data-desc="F">
                        <label for="rating-6"><input type="radio" value="6" name="rating" id="rating-6"  />3 stars</label>
                    </li>
                    <li id="rate-7" data-desc="G">
                        <label for="rating-7"><input type="radio" value="7" name="rating" id="rating-7"  />3.5 stars</label>
                    </li>
                    <li id="rate-8" data-desc="H">
                        <label for="rating-8"><input type="radio" value="8" name="rating" id="rating-8"  />4 stars</label>
                    </li>
                    <li id="rate-9" data-desc="I">
                        <label for="rating-9"><input type="radio" value="9" name="rating" id="rating-9"  />4.5 stars</label>
                    </li>
                    <li id="rate-10" data-desc="J">
                        <label for="rating-10"><input  type="radio" value="10" name="rating" id="rating-10"  />5 stars</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a id="clear-rating" title="" href="#">Clear</a>
                <div class="rate-this" data-desc="Rating">Rating</div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>  
        <ol>
            <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" /></li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#form{
    padding: 2em 3% 0 3%;
}

#form ol li{
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.rating-choice{
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 1.8em;
}

.rating-choice input[type="radio"], .rating-choice label{
    height: 0 !important;
    display: none !important;
}

.rating-choice li{
    float: left !important;
    width: 15px !important;
    height: 30px !important; 
    display: block !important;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

.header{
    font-size: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    width: 100%;
}

.eunrated{
    background-image: url('https://s18.postimg.org/mvu1nzei1/stars150.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -0px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.erating-1{
    background-image: url('https://s18.postimg.org/mvu1nzei1/stars150.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -30px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.erating-2{
    background-image: url('https://s18.postimg.org/mvu1nzei1/stars150.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -60px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.erating-3{
    background-image: url('https://s18.postimg.org/mvu1nzei1/stars150.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -90px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.erating-4{
    background-image: url('https://s18.postimg.org/mvu1nzei1/stars150.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -120px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.erating-5{
    background-image: url('https://s18.postimg.org/mvu1nzei1/stars150.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -150px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.erating-6{
    background-image: url('https://s18.postimg.org/mvu1nzei1/stars150.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -180px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.erating-7{
    background-image: url('https://s18.postimg.org/mvu1nzei1/stars150.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -210px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.erating-8{
    background-image: url('https://s18.postimg.org/mvu1nzei1/stars150.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -240px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.erating-9{
    background-image: url('https://s18.postimg.org/mvu1nzei1/stars150.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -270px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.erating-10{
    background-image: url('https://s18.postimg.org/mvu1nzei1/stars150.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0px -300px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

#clear-rating{
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.rate-this{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: .5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally one might store the review in a database, as a cookie or in the session. These solutions would require the use of a backend using something like PHP, Node.js, etc.

If you want a front-end only solution you might want to take a look at the [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) API's.

Comment: I am using php and mysql but the data wont be stored until the submission is successful.

Comment: You can use AJAX or Sockets to send the data as the user enters it.

Comment: Do you mind giving me an example I'm fairly new to jquery

Comment: thanks for the help I think I will go the php route which solves my problem thanks.